# How can I create Frames in Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Androidstudio, I need to divide the screen into two rows frame. One row should contain three colum frame in xml file.

[image: Need to create this]

Comment: That's nice. Where's the XML with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use a horizontal linearlayout with equal layout_weight attributes. Then put that inside a vertical linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: GridLayout is probably better than nesting LinearLayouts

Comment: Weights in GridLayout are API version dependent

Comment: Even for the support v7 gridlayout?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cuwvu4zxh2ta6ze/Content_Screen.txt?dl=0

Can you help me out to sort out content.xml page in a easier way.